# Consume SOAP with spring boot

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-boot, wsdl

I'm new to spring boot and I'm trying to consume a Soap service from [here](http://www.webservicex.net/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL)

using spring boot somehow my code doesn't seem to work. I have generated classes from that `wsdl` which were saved in my generated-sources folder. How can I consume a remote `wsdl` properly?

**Generated classes folder**

[image]

**Generated classes code**

```
package net.webservicex;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "fromCurrency",
        "toCurrency"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "ConversionRate")
    public class ConversionRate {

    @XmlElement(name = "FromCurrency", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected Currency fromCurrency;
    @XmlElement(name = "ToCurrency", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "string")
    protected Currency toCurrency;

    public Currency getFromCurrency() {
        return fromCurrency;
    }

    public void setFromCurrency(Currency value) {
        this.fromCurrency = value;
    }

    public Currency getToCurrency() {
        return toCurrency;
    }

    public void setToCurrency(Currency value) {
        this.toCurrency = value;
     }
}
```

**ConversionRateResponse.java**

```
package net.webservicex;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
         "conversionRateResult"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "ConversionRateResponse")
    public class ConversionRateResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "ConversionRateResult")
    protected double conversionRateResult;

    public double getConversionRateResult() {
        return conversionRateResult;
    }

    public void setConversionRateResult(double value) {
        this.conversionRateResult = value;
    }
}
```

**Country.java**

```
package net.webservicex;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlType(name = "Currency")
@XmlEnum
public enum Currency {

    AFA,
    ALL,
    DZD,
    ARS,
    USD,
    TRY;
    /*Removed some country codes*/
    public String value() {
        return name();
    }

    public static Currency fromValue(String v) {
        return valueOf(v);
    }

}
```

**ObjectFactory.java**

```
package net.webservicex;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _Double_QNAME = new QName("http://www.webserviceX.NET/", "double");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public ConversionRate createConversionRate() {
        return new ConversionRate();
    }

    public ConversionRateResponse createConversionRateResponse() {
        return new ConversionRateResponse();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/", name = "double")
    public JAXBElement<Double> createDouble(Double value) {
        return new JAXBElement<Double>(_Double_QNAME, Double.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

And I'm calling the service from here, somehow this doesn't work.

```
package com.wsdl;

import net.webservicex.ConversionRate;
import net.webservicex.ConversionRateResponse;
import net.webservicex.Currency;
import net.webservicex.ObjectFactory;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by tenten on 2017/02/15.
 */
@RestController
public class Testing {

    @RequestMapping("/ConversionRate")
    public double conversionRate() {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        ConversionRate conversionRate = objectFactory.createConversionRate();
        ConversionRateResponse conversionRateResponse = objectFactory.createConversionRateResponse();
        Currency usd = Currency.USD;
        usd.value();
        Currency btn = Currency.BTN;
        btn.value();
        conversionRate.setToCurrency(usd);
        conversionRate.setFromCurrency(btn);
        conversionRateResponse.setConversionRateResult(12.00);
        return conversionRateResponse.getConversionRateResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere in your Java classes generated from the WSDL, you should have a Service class which has a method to invoke which will actually execute the request against the server's endpoint.  It doesn't look like you're making use of that in your client code.

Comment: @Cuga yes i'm trying to do that now.